# Floating element position on resize (jQuery/CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I have a hidden layer. When I click on an image the div appears over the image. However, if while the div is showing I resize the page, the the image will shift with the rest of the page elements but the div remains in the same place where it appeared. Is there a way to make it stay relative to the image?

```
$(".myBox").css({"position":"absolute","width":"400px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, which I think that I do, then you should just put `position: relative;` on your image.